# How is a depth map used in 3D reconstruction?

Tags: computer-vision, depth

http://www.yatzer.com/assets/Article/1942/images/Kazuki-Takamatsu-yatzer_8.jpg

I was reading on some 3d reconstruction papers cause I think it is interesting and I have always come across the need to find some "depth map" and when I look it up it appears to be some gray image that supposed to hold depth information. Can someone please explain how this gray image is used to reconstruct the 3D scene?

Answer (score 0):

A depth map is simply a representation of the depth information associated with a given image.

In the simplest case of a [pinhole camera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinhole_camera_model), you can think of it as having the same width and height as the given image, with each pixel value equal to the length of the ray that goes from the  from the camera center to the object whose image is at that same pixel in the given image.

Answer (score 0):

A depth map is generated from the image which is illuminated by uniform intensity focused on the objects. Any depth map is having values from 0 to 255. If some object is near to the camera from which the original image is taken, will have highest intensity value i.e. 255 and vice versa. This information is used for regeneration of 3D image.